# Border goes inside div when screen is resized (Firefox)

Tags: css, firefox

Like the title says and the attached image shows - what is creating this issue?

As I resize the window using Firefox the white border jumps in and out of place. If I reload the page in a position where the border is inside the div it stays that way. This issue only occurs on Firefox.

I've tried adding box-sizing: border-box, changing the div width and height, changing the line-height, changing the display.. I just cannot find what could be causing this issue. Any advice would be appreciated!

[Image showing the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKKwK.png)

Comment: Attachment missing. Give the HTML code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Apologies, this is my first post after all! There is so much code I wouldn't know what to post and what not to. I'd like an idea of what the issue might be before we get into details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the solution myself by adding "transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.0, 1.0);" to the div itself. Hopefully this can help someone else having the same issue.